# OroPlatform: Custom HTML column on grid

Tags: symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

#### Context

I'm trying to build a custom html column for a custom entity grid. I have searched in the Oro Platform Core to find the right entries for the `datagrids.yml`

```
columns:
  id:
    label: ID
    frontend_type: integer
  name:
    label: app.vehicule_type.fields.name
  logo:
    label: app.vehicule_type.fields.logo
    type: twig
    frontend_type: html
    template: BaltimoreAppBundle:Attachment:Datagrid/Property/image.html.twig
```

`BaltimoreAppBundle` is my bundle name and `image.html.twig` is the custom template file.

#### Issue

OroPlatform/Symfony can't understand my bundle alias `BaltimoreAppBundle`, so I've got an error.

[image]

Any idea why my alias doesn't works ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure the bundle is registered at the symfony kernel by running:

```sh
php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.bundles --format=json
```

The key in the output array is the bundle name that should be used for the template path.
If it's not, follow the [Bundle Creation Guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/extension/create-bundle/).

Then make sure that the path to the template you refer is correct. For the one you use, inside the loaded BaltimoreAppBundle bundle, you should have the template file path: `Resources/views/Attachment/Datagrid/Property/image.html.twig`.

If it doesn't help, make sure the application cache is fresh by dropping it, using `rm -rf var/cache/*`, and regenerating it manually, using `php bin/console cache:warmup`.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was coming from the `Resources` path to my templates. I have miswritten the `path` by forgotten the `s` at the end of `views`. It could be useful for other people.
By the way, I have to specify that I'm using Symfony Local Web Server for development and I have to use `symfony console cache:warmup` instead of `php bin/console cache:warmup` because I have encountered some issues with it.

Comment: It's correct. With the Symfony server, you have to use `symfony console` instead of `php bin/console`.